# How to get a named list element in R if the appearance of the element is conditional?

Tags: r, list, element, named

I want to include a list element `c` in a list `L` in R and name it `C`.
The example is as follows:

```
a=c(1,2,3)
b=c("a","b","c")
c=rnorm(3)
L<-list(A=a,
        B=b,
        C=c)
print(L)

## $A
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## $B
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
## 
## $C
## [1] -2.2398424  0.9561929 -0.6172520
```

Now I want to introduce a condition on `C`, so it is only included in
the list if `C.bool==T`:

```
C.bool<-T
L<-list(A=a,
        B=b,
        if(C.bool) C=c)

print(L)

## $A
## [1] 1 2 3
## 
## $B
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] -2.2398424  0.9561929 -0.6172520
```

Now, however, the list element of `c` is not being named as specified in
the list statement. What's the trick here?

Edit: The intention is to only include the element in the list if the condition is met (no NULL shoul be included otherwise). Can this be done within the core definition of the list?

Comment: your code above will still introduce a 3rd list element (albeit `NULL`) if `C.bool` is FALSE . Is that your intent?

Comment: `if (C.bool) {L$C <- c}` ?

Comment: @Ricky Thanks for mentioning that point. My intention was indeed, that no element at all is included if C.bool==F. Is there a way to do this without adding C outside the core definition of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do it "without adding C outside the core definition of the list?" but if you're content with two `list`s in a single `c` then:

```
L <- c(list(A=a, B=b), if(C.bool) list(C=c))
```

If you really want one `list` but don't mind subsetting after creation then

```
L <- list(A=a, B=b, C=if(C.bool) c)[c(TRUE, TRUE, C.bool)]
```

(pace David Arenburg, `isTRUE()` omitted for brevity)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you want to keep the names

```
L2 <-list(A=a,
        B=b,
        C = if (TRUE) c)
```

You can of course replace `TRUE` with the statement containing `C.bool`

Comment: The correct practice is to use `isTRUE` as in `if (isTRUE(C.bool))` because your statement will return `TRUE` for both `C.bool = "true"` and `C.bool = 1` (or any other number above zero).

Comment: yes, but `C.bool` is logical (as the name says too)

Comment: I still think it is better to maintain your code bulletproof as much as possible. Do you find `isTRUE` hard to type? This is also important to educate future readers with correct practices. If someone will see this in the future, he won't necessarily understand that this could be used only in a special case. Hell, I would recommend using `isTRUE` in *any* case.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the `if` statement outside the core definition of the list, like this:

```
L <- list(A = a, B=  b) 
if (isTRUE(C.bool)) L$C <- c
#> L
#$A
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$B
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
#
#$C
#[1] -0.7631459  0.7353929 -0.2085646
```

(Edit with `isTRUE()` owing to the comment by @DavidArenburg)

Comment: Hmm. This code won't work, because `L$C` doesn't exsist anymore after you did `L <- list(A = a, B=  b)`. This should be just `if (isTRUE(C.bool)) L$C <- c else L$C <- NULL`. This way you won't need to retype all the rest of the variables too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm surprised by this comment. The code works on my computer. I removed all variables in the global environment and ran the code again. Can you please double-check?

Comment: Oh right, OP has `c` in his global environment, I didn't notice that. I wonder if this true in real life. I mean why will you need all the vectors both in a list and in the global environment? Either way, my suggestion will be more general as you won't need to retype all the elements into `L` again, rather just remove the unwanted vector by condition.

Answer (score 0):

As a combination of the previous answers by @MamounBenghezal, @user20637
and the comment made by @DavidArenburg, I would suggest this generalized
version that does not depend on the length of the list:

```
L <- Filter(Negate(is.null),
       x = list(A = a, B = b, C = if (isTRUE(C.bool)) c, D = "foo"))
```

Comment: `Filter(Negate(is.null))` removes all NULL list elements, whether null because of `X.bool` or otherwise. A list length independent subset solution can use recycling, thus `L <- list(A=a, B=b, C=if(C.bool) c, D="foo")[if(C.bool) TRUE else -3]`